# How to send FCM push notifications from/to two different apps with different package names and different firebase projects? Is it even possible?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already have FCM tokens saved in Db which I will later use to identify user and send notifications but I'm confused as to is it possible to do with apps that have different package names.

Comment: Give us more information. What have you done so far? Post the code depending the problem. Do you have error messages? What idea is your solution about by now?